# Integer operators in bash

Tags: bash

How can I use `++`, `+=`, `*=`, etc operators in bash script. Examples please.

Example in C++:

```
int a = 7;
a = ++a + ++a;
printf("%d", a);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but your C++ example is flawed, because the + operator is not a [sequence point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point).

Answer (score 4):

In Bash you can do things like:

```
a=1
echo $((++a + ++a))
# result: 5, but don't write code like that

echo $((a+=4))
echo $((a*=4))
echo $((a/=2))
echo $((a-=1))

a=1; b=1
echo $((++a + ++b)) # Result: 4
echo $((--a + --b)) # Result: 2

a=1; b=1
echo $((a++ + b++)) # Result: 2
echo $((a-- + b--)) # Result: 4
```

The largest number that bash can handle is

```
echo $((2**63 - 1))
# Result: 9,223,372,036,854,775,807
```

Comment: I really hope for bash that the first result isn't 7. :P

Comment: @htorque, good point, in bash a=1; ++a + ++a is 5.

Comment: Actually, like in C, the result of `++a + ++a` is undefined. Also, there's not really any reason to do two increments on the same variable on the same line.

Answer (score 2):

```
a=7; echo $a
#  7
((a+=a)); echo $a
# 14
((a*=-1)); echo $a
# -14
((++a)); echo $a
# -13
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a wide argument, you should definitely go through `bash` man page, and through some good bash guide, as this [BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide)

In [this page](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/CompoundCommands#Arithmetic_Evaluation) you will find some examples.